# Stop Ansible from replacing double quotes with single quotes

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use a variable containing double quotes in a task, but Ansible automatically replaces the quotes with single qoutes.

Running the task with a literal string works:

```yaml
- name: Add test monitor
  lucasheld.uptime_kuma.monitor:
    api_url: "https://test.example.com"
    api_token: "{{ token }}"
    type: keyword
    name: testing
    url: http://10.11.10.10:9005/v1/dns/status
    keyword: |-
      {"test":"this works"}
    state: present
```

Output:

```
{"test":"this works"}
```

If I replace the keyword parameter with a variable, the quotes get replaced and a space is inserted:

```yaml
- name: Add test monitor
  lucasheld.uptime_kuma.monitor:
    api_url: "https://test.example.com"
    api_token: "{{ token }}"
    type: keyword
    name: testing
    url: http://IPADDRESS/v1/dns/status
    keyword: |-
      {{ keyword }}
    state: present
  vars:
    keyword: |-
      {"test":"does not work"}
```

Output:

```
{'test': 'does not work'}
```

I have tried escaping the quotes, multi-line and single-line parameter notation, and several variations of this. The only thing that does seem to work is adding a space before the variable (`{{ " " + keyword }}`), but this does not work for the downstream application.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

EDIT: The example above is in JSON format, but the `keyword` variable could contain any kind of string, not just JSON.

Comment: In short => `keyword: "{{ keyword | to_json }}"`. If the extra space is a problem => `keyword: "{{ keyword | to_json(separators=(',',':')) }}"`. Note that there is no need to declare `keyword` as a full string with this. A standard yaml declaration will work equally.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that the keyword variable could contain any kind of strings, not just JSON. Ultimately, I just need to parse exactly what is defined in the variable.

Comment: In case it contains something else than json, you will not get the above issue. One thing you can try is mark your variable as unsafe so that Ansible does not pass it to Jinja templating engine. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings

Comment: @Zeitounator that was promising, but unfortunately does not work. As for the json solution, the task could use the keyword variable from different sources so it's unknown what the format will be. Using `to_json` would result discrepancies for non-json formatted strings from what I have tried.

Comment: If you mark as unsafe, you don't use `to_json`, You use the raw value from the variable.

Comment: Yep I tried that, without `to_json`, but the string still gets changed oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I replace the keyword parameter with a variable, the quotes get replaced and a space is inserted*

Right, that is the expected behavior because of [Templating (Jinja2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html).

> *Any ideas how I can get this to work? ... Stop Ansible from replacing double quotes with single quotes*

As already mentioned within the comments, use [Unsafe or raw strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    keyword: '{"test":"does not work"}'
    keyword_raw: |-
      {% raw %}{"test":"does not work"}{% endraw %}
    keyword_unsafe: !unsafe {"test":"does not work"}
    keyword_unsafe_quote: !unsafe '{"test":"does not work"}'

  tasks:

  - copy:
      dest: api.test
      content: "{{ keyword }}" # or keyword_raw | keyword_unsafe | keyword_unsafe_quote
```

will result in any case into an output of

```json
~/test$ cat api.test
{"test": "does not work"}
```